# Variable Never Assigned to C#

Tags: c#

I'm missing something simple here, I know it. My private variables are "not assigned," but from my (limited) knowledge they are. What am I missing? I've looked at the other similar questions, but I don't quite understand the answers (or even the questions!). Please help.

```
public class Weapon
{
    private string mName;
    private double mRange;
    private double mDamage;

    public string Name
    {
       get { return mName; }
       set { mName=value; }
    }

    public double Range
    {
       get { return mRange; }
       set 
       {
          if (value >= 0)
              mRange=value;
          else
              throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Range");
       }
    }

    public double Damage
    {
       get { return mDamage; }
       set
       {
          if (value >= 0)
              mDamage=value;
          else
              throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Damage");
       }
    }

    public Weapon(string n, double d)
    {
       n = Name;
       d = Damage;
    }
    public Weapon (string n, double r, double d)
    {
       n = Name;
       r = Range;
       d = Damage;
    }
```

Comment: You have your assignment operations reversed. The left hand side is the variable that *gets* the value.  For ex `n = Name;` should be `Name = n;`

Comment: In your constructor, seems you should swap the variables on the two sides of equal signs...

Comment: Of course it's that simple. It always is. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You have your constructor assignments backwards.

This:

```
public Weapon(string n, double d)
{
    n = Name;
    d = Damage;
}
public Weapon (string n, double r, double d)
{
    n = Name;
    r = Range;
    d = Damage;
}
```

Should be this:

```
public Weapon(string n, double d)
{
    Name = n;
    Damage = d;
}
public Weapon (string n, double r, double d)
{
    Name = n;
    Range = r;
    Damage = d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Weapon
{
    private string _name;
    private double _range;
    private double _damage;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }

    public double Range
    {
        get
        {
            return _range;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
                _range = value;
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Range");
        }
    }

    public double Damage
    {
        get
        {
            return _damage;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
                _damage = value;
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Damage");
        }
    }

    public Weapon(string n, double d)
    {
        Name = n;
        Damage = d;
    }
    public Weapon(string n, double r, double d)
    {
        Name = n;
        Range = r;
        Damage = d;
    }
}
```